# Аналог псевдокласса :nth в CSS?

Tags: css, jquery

Если использовать Jquery, то там есть возможность выбора номера элемента из всей выборки (:nth).
А в чистом CSS есть только :nth-child, который ищет элементы среди детей?

То есть селектор

```
$('.selectors:nth(1) .t-d:nth(1)')
```

в Jquery работает. В CSS пишет `is not a valid selector.`

А есть ли аналогичное поведение на чистом css?

Comment: Не работает такой селектор. Он не находит элементы если они лежат в разных родителях.

Comment: Так вопрос как раз в том чтобы искать элементы которые лежат в разных местах в разных родителях.

Comment: виноват, прошу прощения, недоглядел

Comment: @manking на примере реальной задачи можете показать зачем это нужно?

Comment: о какой версии jQuery речь? не вижу в документации информации о селекторе nth - https://api.jquery.com/?s=nth

Comment: @AndreyFedorov
Конкретно у нас для автоматических тестов, найти на странице элементы под определенным селектором. Логика основана на чистом css и эмуляторе браузера puppeteer. Пока вариант только в том, чтобы предварительно задавать 1 класс с помощью jquery.

Comment: @Grundy
В документации нет информации, но оно работает. Я случайно попробовал и оно заработало.

Comment: @manking, в jquery нет такой функции, возможно стоит какой-то плагин.  Да, не так пробовал, в  селектооре действительно есть

Comment: Получается в чистом CCS этого нет, так как для этого требуется выполнить несколько проходов? А в jquery внутри это реализовано.

Comment: @manking, добавил ответ. Про количество проходов не понял.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Все селекторы с указанием индекса в CSS вычисляют индекс внутри родителя, а не внутри выборки

---

Селектор `:nth`, является [синонимом](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/src/sizzle.js#L1779) селектора [`:eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/), который в jQuery объявлен устаревшим и рекомендованным к замене на одноименный метод.

---

В css есть похожий селектор `:nth-child` однако он ведет отсчет индекса элемента внутри внутри родителя, а не в конечной выборке, поэтому может выбирать несколько элементов вместо одного. Сам индекс ведет счет от 1.

```js
// Applies yellow background color to a single <li>
$("ul.nav li:eq(1)").css("backgroundColor", "#ff0");
```

```css
ul.nav li:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
  <li>List 1, item 1</li>
  <li>List 1, item 2</li>
  <li>List 1, item 3</li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav">
  <li>List 2, item 1</li>
  <li>List 2, item 2</li>
  <li>List 2, item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ответ не по теме вопроса. Интересен не обзор селектора :nth-child, а конкретно :nth либо :eq. То есть селектор конечной выборки, а не внутри одного родителя. Как я понял чистый css такое не поддерживает.

Comment: @manking, об этом как раз и говорится в ответе

Comment: @manking, переформатировал ответ